# Retaining a search value after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a HTML page with a form which passes values to an external PHP page.

```
<form method="post" action="getContent.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="fromTest" id="fromTest"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="untilTest" id="untilTest"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="latTest" id="latTest"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="longTest" id="longTest"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="search1" id="search1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="search2" id="search2"/>
    <input type="submit" class="sendAll" value="Gather News!">
</form>
```

This side of the code is working fine, the values are great. My issue is with retaining this information and reusing it after this php page has been called and returned back to my html file.

I'm looking to set the first search term '#search1' to replace the value inside of feed1mainheader.

```
  <div id="feed1MainHeader"></div>
```

I understand the way to do it, I've used it a few other times through this site but my issue is losing the value when the page is refreshed?

```
   $('#feed1MainHeader').val($("#search2").val());
```

I've read a bit about cookies but I'm extremely new to this and I'm not quite understanding how to implement them for this sort of function?

Any ideas?

Comment: you could make it a URL parameter (e.g. www.yoursite.com/something?param1=val&param2=anotherval ... etc) and pull it out from there. In fact, the way you've set your form up, it should work that way.

Comment: @pennstatephil No it won't, it is set up as a POST instead of a GET. Look into saving the POST variable into a session variable.

Comment: when you say an external php page what exactly do you mean? another domain? have you consider making an ajax call? there for the page does not refresh and you still maintain all of you original values.

Answer (score 2):

There is no possible way that the browser would itself save the value for you. But there are some other tricks that you can use in this matter.

#### `autocomplete` method

In this method, you use the input field's property of autocomplete. In which browser would keep a track of each and every input data in that particular field.

Here is the example

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="somename" />
```

First time it won't show you anything. Second time it will show the last value submitted then it will show you a list of value submitted through this field.

#### `localStorage` method

You can store the value in the localStorage (**HTML5 enabled** browsers only).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

You can store the value in the browser (client) device and then access it again using JavaScript.

#### Caching it down

You can use Caching service to store the data and values the user provides you in the Browser in form of cache.

JavaScript or Server-side Language can be used to store the cache files.

These are some of the methods that you can implement. Autocomplete method is the easiest and simplest of them all. However you can use other methods too. They will save your last inputs and provide you with them when you need them.

Good luck!

Comment: A cookie would only save the last value that you searched on, whereas as suggested, using autocomplete should prompt you for anything you have previously searched for that matches the characters keyed so far.  Sounds like the best solution to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great answer. I'm just a bit to new to completely understand whats going on. With autocomplete, is the browser storing the values somewhere I can access to change the value of my mainheader? 

Localstorage seems pretty bang on what I've been looking for but going through the examples I'm not sure how to implement it for the above code. 

Any ideas? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Please note that the autocomplete method is available for input elements where user can add values. In hidden elements it is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using local storage like:

```
localStorage.setItem("searchitem", $("#search2").val());
```

and on refresh check if exists. If it exists load it